# Authentication Component: Which pattern can I use? (PHP)

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, authentication

I'm trying to build an auth component as decoupled as possible, allowing different kinds of authentication (eg: http, digest, database, etc), just like zend_auth: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html

Does the pattern they used have a name? 
Can you recommend me a different approach?
Maybe the Bridge or Strategy patterns?

Comment: You should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

well from the link you provided:

> Zend_Auth provides an API for authentication and includes concrete authentication adapters

and Zend_auth is Singleton  itself.

So your solution would be a combination of singleton and set of adapters base on common interface. I think the introduction part of Zend_Auth documentation is really well described including the code-samples.

Comment: I don't use singleton anymore (it ruins unit-testing). In fact, Zend itself is being re-written to remove static calls (among other things). I hope they release Zend 2 soon so I can see how they improved it, or even I could start using it.